# Troubleshooting the tag: can we diagnose it as unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting).

At best, *troubleshooting* describes a type of activity, though not a very specific one, and not one in which people would be likely to have a particular interest or expertise.

At worst, the tag is applicable to every situation where something is not working as expected. This seems to be the way it is being used on the majority of the 223 posts that currently have it.

Can we remove this tag?

---

<sub>Credit to [jokerdino](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54954170#54954170) and [Eliah Kagan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3877?m=54953063#54953063) for the title of this post :)</sub>

Comment: Certainly looks like [a meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).